# Check if String contains unicode character

Tags: c#, contains

I have a button whose text contains a black circle

`Button.Text = "This is the button text &#x25CF;"`

Later when I click on the button I need to check if the Text contains the circle character, however `Button.Text.Contains("&x25CF;")` returns False

How can I search a string for the Unicode characters?

Comment: The WPF Button class doesn't have a Text property. Besides that, unicode escape sequences are written like `\u25CF` in C#. `&x25CF;` is XML or XAML.

Comment: Please try this: `Button.Text.Contains(((char)0x25CF).ToString())`

Comment: You mean "string contains escaped unicode character as valid for HTML syntax"? Every character in a .NET string is a unicode character. Also know that the act of giving that string to the button may end up converting it and thus getting rid of the escape format.

Comment: @Clemens Its actually a custom control, but for clarity sake I called it a Button. The second part of your answer is what I was looking for

Comment: "for *clarity* sake I called it a Button", that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C#, unicode character escape sequences are written as `\u25CF`, while `&#x25CF;` is XML or HTML.

So you should write

```
Text.Contains("\u25CF")
```